# How many times do you need to double previous result to get at least $10^{82}$?

Tags: exponential-sum

This is pretty straightforward, but I'd like to study, how find out, how many times do you need to double previous result of calculation to get some sum, for example: $10^{82}$

1. $1\times 2 = 2$
2. $2\times 2 = 4$
3. $4\times 2 = 8$
4. $8\times 2 = 16$

n. $x\times 2 \geq 10^{82}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $n$th step is $2^n$. If you want $2^n\geq A$, then you want 
$$n = \log_2(2^n) \geq \log_2(A) = \frac{\ln(A)}{\ln(2)} = \frac{\log_{10}A}{\log_{10}(2)}.$$

So the first $n$ at which $2^n\geq A$ will be the least positive integer greater than or equal to $\log_2(A)$, which is denoted
$$\left\lceil \log_2A \right\rceil.$$

Comment: ...and, in particular, $A = 10^{82}$ implies $\log_2 A = \log_{10} A / \log_{10} 2 \approx 82 / 0.30103 \approx 272.4$, and thus $\lceil \log_2 A \rceil = 273$.

Comment: Added with the last comment, this was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For good ballpark estimates, use the fact that $2^{10}=1024\approx 1000$.  So $10$ doublings is about the same as multiplying by $1000$. Since $10^{82}=10\times 1000^{27}$, we can see that $270$ doublings will get us past $10^{81}$. There is some slack, and another $3$ doublings get us over.

Comment: While I saw this also very interesting and working approach, I accepted other answer because it gave more precise and general solution for my purpose. Thanks.